# Gmail python sdk : get messages by history id

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gmail, google-cloud-pubsub

I have setup Google pub-sub on my gmail service account. As a result, as soon as an email is getting delivered to this email, a notification message is getting delivered to the configured pub-sub topic. Followed this guideline https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push

I've written a small Flask api to which the the notification message is sent by the Google pub-sub topic as part of subscription.

Using the message data I'm getting the history id and trying to read the message trough that history id. Below is the code snippet:

```
def get_messages(self, history_id):
    messages = []

    histories = self.gmail_client.users().history().list(userId=self.userId, startHistoryId=history_id).execute()

    print(histories)

    if histories and 'history' in histories:
        for history in (history for history in histories['history'] if 'messages' in history):
            for message in history['messages']:
                try:
                    message_data = self.gmail_client.users().messages().get(userId=self.userId, id=message['id']).execute()
                    messages.append(message_data)
                except Exception:
                    pass

    return messages
```

However, after 1-2 times initially, I'm nont gettig any messages at all with the corresponding history id.

Is there anything miissing from my side?

Answer (score 2):

Following the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#receiving_notifications) to receive notifications, the `historyId` that you are getting is the new mailbox history ID for the user, so the latest at the notification time.

If you are using this `historyId` from the Pub/Sub notification message to call the function `get_messages()`, this history ID is being passed to the `users.history.list` [method](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/gmail_v1.users.history.html) as `startHistoryId`, and then as the "latest" history ID (at the time), it's very likely that there are no new delivered messages since then (unless you are getting many emails in a very short amount of time). And then as result you get no messages, you need to use a previous/older `historyId`, it could be from a previous notification message.

> `startHistoryId`: string, Required. Returns history records after the
> specified `startHistoryId`. The supplied `startHistoryId` should be
> obtained from the `historyId` of a message, thread, or previous `list`
> response. History IDs increase chronologically but are not contiguous
> with random gaps in between valid IDs. Supplying an invalid or out of
> date `startHistoryId` typically returns an `HTTP 404` error code. A
> `historyId` is typically valid for at least a week, but in some rare
> circumstances may be valid for only a few hours. If you receive an
> `HTTP 404` error response, your application should perform a full
> sync. If you receive no `nextPageToken` in the response, there are no
> updates to retrieve and you can store the returned `historyId` for a
> future request.

Something to keep in mind here, is that your code seems fine; however, without the input used to call the function `get_messages()`, and the output from the method `users.history.list`, it's a bit difficult to know what's happening when you run your code. I would suggest to keep track of the previous `historyId` and use them, instead of using immediately the `historyId` that you are getting from the Pub/Sub notification message.

*When sharing the input & output, please make sure to remove any sensitive or personal data that could be included.*

Some additional pointers on your code, according to the documentation, the `users.history.list` method [returns](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/gmail_v1.users.history.html#list) an object of the form:

```
{
  "historyId": "A String",
  "nextPageToken": "A String",
  "history": [
    {
      "labelsRemoved": [
        {
          "message": { # An email message.
          },
          "labelIds": [
            "A String",
          ],
        },
      ],
      "messagesAdded": [
        {
          "message": { # An email message.
          },
        },
      ],
      "labelsAdded": [
        {
          "message": { # An email message.
          },
          "labelIds": [
            "A String",
          ],
        },
      ],
      "id": "A String",
      "messagesDeleted": [
        {
          "message": { # An email message.
          },
        },
      ],
      "messages": [
        {  # An email message.
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

Where the message (email message) objects have the following structure:

```
"message": { # An email message.
  "threadId": "A String",
  "labelIds": [
    "A String",
  ],
  "sizeEstimate": 42,
  "id": "A String",
  "raw": "A String",
  "payload": {
    "mimeType": "A String",
    "partId": "A String",
    "parts": [],
    "headers": [
      {
        "name": "A String",
        "value": "A String",
      },
    ],
    "body": {
      "data": "A String",
      "size": 42,
      "attachmentId": "A String",
    },
    "filename": "A String",
  },
  "snippet": "A String",
  "historyId": "A String",
  "internalDate": "A String",
}
```

On the other hand the `users.messages.get` method [returns](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/gmail_v1.users.messages.html#get) an email message object with the same structure (see previous snippet).

Based on this, if you are getting the message IDs from the `users.history.list` method (e.g. `history['messages'][0]['id']`), then you are also getting the email message objects. Thus, what you are trying to do by iterating the list `history['messages']` to get every message by ID using the `users.messages.get` method, is the same as doing the following:

```
messages = history['messages']
```

Or if you would like to get something more specific as the content of `body.data` under `payload` you could use:

```
history['messages'][0]['payload']['body']['data']

# The index [0] is to point to the first message on the list, 
# if you are iterating the list, the index is not necessary
# e.g. message['payload']['body']['data']
```

This way, you don't need to iterate over the message IDs and use the `users.messages.get` method to get one by one the email messages, as you already have them from the `users.history.list` method.

Comment: Great answer. This post also helped me understand the situation :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42090593/gmail-watch-user-inbox-history-getmessagesadded-is-not-returning-the-new-messag